Using ColorFunction with PolarPlot
I am trying to colour a function using ColorFunction in PolarPlot. When I plot $f(x)=\sin x+\cos 2x$ on the real line, I get the desired outcome, but I can't figure out how to transfer that to the circular plot. I've read the documentation but I must be missing something. Any help is appreciated!
Plot[Sin[1 x] + Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][y]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]


PolarPlot[1, {\[Theta], 0 , 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.05], 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, \[Theta], r}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][Sin[\[Theta]] + Cos[2 \[Theta]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-2, 1.125}}]]


The fix doesn't seem to be to use ColorFunctionScaling->False. Below, I present the real line plot of the function with this attribute. We can see that at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$, the colour agrees, however, these values are $0$ and $-2$ respectively and so should be different as in the above plot.
Plot[Sin[1 x] + Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][y]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]


PolarPlot[1, {\[Theta], 0 , 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.05], 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, \[Theta], r}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][Sin[\[Theta]] + Cos[2 \[Theta]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-2, 1.125}}]]



min = FindMinimum[
  Sin[\[Theta]] + Cos[2 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

$\{-2.,\{\theta \to -1.5708\}\}$
max = FindMaximum[
  Sin[\[Theta]] + Cos[2 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

$\{1.125,\{\theta \to 0.25268\}\}$

PolarPlot[1, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}
 , PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]
 , ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, \[Theta], r}
   , (ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Rescale[Sin[\[Theta]] + Cos[2 \[Theta]], {First@min, 
       First@max}]])]
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}
 , PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {First@min, First@max}}]
 ]




Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

You're welcome. Thanks for the accept. @AP

Your problem is the attribute "ColorFunctionScaling". With this attribute set to "True", only values between 0 and 1 are fed to the color function. However, in the polar plot theta is varying between 0 and 2Pi. Therefore set the attribute to False and change the bar legend to a range of {0,2Pi}:
PolarPlot[1, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.05], 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, \[Theta], r}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][Sin[\[Theta]] + Cos[2 \[Theta]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 2 Pi}}]]



Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. I've edited the question to show  this. Using ColorFunctionScaling->False sets the value of the angle at $\pi/2$ radians (the north pole) to be $0$ which is correct, but then it sets the value at $3\pi/2$ to also be $0$ when in fact it is about $-2$.
